# Php mail with html sontent in inline css styles

Tags: gmail-api

I have written a php mail with html content with inline css styles but when I execute that php mail I'm recieving mail in microsoft outlook but not in gmail app. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked your spams ? Gmail has an hard anti spam politic and sometimes it goes directly into spams or you don't ever receive the mail